# Powershell to zip and archive

Tags: powershell

I'm currently doing an IT course online and one of my assignments to is archive and zip three files using Powershell.

I am going to use 7-Zip to zip and archive the files. The process of how to do this is not very clear.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would really appreciated.

I've entered this is PS but I am not really sure if it's correct or not.

This is the command I need to use:

```
Compress-Archive -Path Earth, Mercury, Venus Planets.zip
```

In the folder where the above files are, do I need to put those files into a folder first?

Would the command look like this after adding the directory?

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:>\Users\Sams\Documents\Earth\Mercury\Venus\ ~\Desktop\EarthMercuryVenusArchive.zip
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All you'll need to know for what you ask should be provided by the built-in help.

```
Get-Command -Name '*archive*'

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                                 
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                                 
Function        Compress-Archive                                   1.0.1.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive                                                           
Function        Expand-Archive                                     1.0.1.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive  

# Get paramter, example, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

(Get-Command -Name Compress-Archive).Parameters
Get-help -Name Compress-Archive -Examples
Get-help -Name Compress-Archive -Full
Get-help -Name Compress-Archive -Online


(Get-Command -Name Expand-Archive).Parameters
Get-help -Name Expand-Archive -Examples
Get-help -Name Expand-Archive -Full
Get-help -Name Expand-Archive -Online
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two archive commands `Compress-Archive` and `Expand-Archive`

To figure out what each one does and what parameters are required, try using `Get-Help`

Example:

```
Get-Help Compress-Archive
```

Or take a look at the online documents for the two commands [Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/?view=powershell-5.1)